# Elasticsearch: Count Document that Have Duplicated data in Field

Tags: elasticsearch, count, duplicates, field

I am writing to ask if there is a way in Elasticsearch to get a `count` of all documents that have duplicates in a field: Consider a document in Elasticsearch that look like following:

```
{ "duplicated-attr": "test test" }
```

This very simple document has one field: `duplicated-attr`; and has as it value `test test`. It should only have the following value: `test`, and thereby be stored in Elasticsearch as follows:

```
{ "duplicated-attr": "test" }
```

However, that is not the case with our index; and, I want to identify a way to list/count of all the document where this type of duplication has occurred in a field in Elasticsearch?

The `mapping` for the contrived example above pretty closely matches the `mapping` we use in the index:

```
{
  "mappings":
  {
    "properties":
    {
      "searchProperties":
      {
        "duplicated-attr":
        {
          "type": "text",
          "fields":
          {
            "keyword":
            {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 512
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also share the mapping type of the `duplicated-attr` field? Also the number of documents that your index contains would be helpful

Comment: @Val: Please find the mapping added. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.